# String#replaceFirst for charakter slash or /

Tags: java, minecraft

Dear fellow programmers

I'm developing a Java plugin for my minecraft server. Now my issue is that I have a / in a string and want to replace it with nothing AKA "". I tried to use "/", "/", "\/" and "slash" in the first parameter of the replaceFirst method. Either didn't work.

Here is my code:

```
if (command.startsWith("/")) {
            command.replaceFirst("\\/", "");
            System.out.println("After replace: " + command);
            target.performCommand(command);
            sender.sendMessage("§5" + target.getName() + "§a performed the command §5/" + command);
        }
```

If you know how I could do this thanks for your help in advance :)

Comment: What you have already tried should be working.  Please include the actual code.

Comment: Strings are immutable, so you have to get the return value: `command = command.replaceFirst("/", "");`

Comment: @Andreas That makes sence. Thanks for your answer. And I'm sorry if I didn't find your duplicate. That's exactly not what I would type in my search bar in this case ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Strings are **immutable**. `command.replaceFirst` does not change the string that the `command` reference is pointing at; it creates a new string, and returns a reference to this new string. You'd have to write e.g. `command = command.replaceFirst(...)`.
2. Given that `replaceFirst` uses regexes, this is needlessly complicated. Try `command = command.substring(1);` instead, to lop off the first character.

Comment: Or just use `String#replace`

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen That's not an option for me because there may be more than one slash and I only want to replace the first one